# Webpack require.ensure with dynamic string path

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, require, commonjs

I need to require modules dynamically for asynchronous loading with webpack. My goal is to loop through an array and load these modules (it's for my react-router purposes, not important here).

This is my code:

```
const arr = ['some-module', 'module-2'];
arr.map(moduleName => {
  require.ensure([], require => {
    if(process.env.IS_BROWSER) { //for react server-render because of babel 6
      cb(null, require(moduleName));
    }
    else {
      cb(null, require(moduleName).default);
    }
  });
}
```

It works well on server, but on the frontend, the additional bundles are not made and loaded. Do you please know how to solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you might aware that Webpack is a static module bundler, all the modules should be resolved statically. It doesn't support resolving the assets expressions which are completely dynamic.

It can resolve some dynamic expression statically something like

```
var a = 'a';
require.ensure([], function (require) {
   // all dynamic entry modules inside /dynamic/ folder
   console.log(require('./dynamic/' + a));
});
```

If you want to generate one chunk per module, you can use require.context in combination with bundle-loader.

```
var a = './a';
require.context('bundle!./app')(a)(function(moduleTest){
    console.log(moduleTest);
});
```